# How to execute SQL query and return an object?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

So I'm migrating from .NET Framework to .NET 6. I'm in a function where the guy I took over from spends line 693 - 760 generating a query in SQL and getting the result with this:

```cs
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<CustomObject>(sqlQuery.ToString(), parameters.ToArray());
```

But I am very kindly being informed that:

> 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no accessible extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using `System.Data.Entity` as the docs [say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). I know I can do `db.[TableName].FromSqlRaw`, but I can't use that because the object I  need isn't in the database.

I've got the following packages but I may be missing something?

[image: EntityFramework (6.4.4) Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (6.0.7) Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (6.0.7) Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (6.0.7) Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (6.0.7)]

Comment: If only there were working examples somewhere on the internet.

Just to point out EF6 is different to .Net 6.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/ vs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: You have referenced both EF6 and EF Core 6, you need to figure out which one you are actually using (I would guess the latter) and then you use `db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw` for example, which you probably would have found if you have looked for it.

Comment: You can use this with EF Core https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.SqlQuery/6.0.0-preview1

Comment: @DavidG I had found those, but they return the amount of rows affected and not what I need

Comment: You need to use `Keyless` entities, but first you need to fix your project up a bit. You have referenced both Entity Framework 6 and EFCore. Remove EntityFramework 6.4.4  from your project. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Ah Sorry, just saw you are migrating from EF to EFCore, just use Keyless entities, you will need to change it up a bit, but it works. I recently migrated from EF to EFCore and I had to do the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I recently went through the same process migrating from EF to EF Core.

If your Entity is NOT in the database, and is just based on an SQL query, you can use `Keyless` entities and map to a `NULL` view. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

1. Add your entity class (which should match the result from query)

   ```
   public class Person
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }  
   }
   ```
2. Add the collection to your `DbContext` as a `DbSet`:

   ```
   public class FooContext : DbContext
   {
       ....
       public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   To make the entity keyless, you can either use the `[Keyless]` attribute, or in Fluent syntax in `DbContext`:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder
                .Entity<Person>()
                .HasNoKey()
                // ToView should be NULL, or you can Map to an SQL View here
                .ToView(null);
   }
   ```
3. Then you can query the `Persons` like:

   ```
   var paramss = new[] { new SqlParameter("@foo", 123) };

   fooContext.Persons.FromSqlRaw("SELECT Name, DateOfBirth From Persons", paramss).AsEnumerable();
   ```

Comment: This looks promising. It'll be a little while until I can see it in action, because good lord there's a lot to migrate here :v

Comment: @JaDa yes took me about a week to migrate our solution. But here is some docs I followed: https://www.mikee.se/posts/migrating_from_ef6_to_ef_core

Comment: well it looks like it mostly worked. I had to give some fields a [NotMapped] and now it's complaining that "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values". Fun times, as they say!

Comment: Just call me hackerman. I added a "DTO" version of that object where I made all fields nullable. And on that a Map function that turns them into the non-DTO. Turns out that works :v